# How would I display a 3rd order polynomial boundary line for linear regression in Python?

Tags: python, linear-regression

Assume I have an **m x 2** dataset **X** and run a linear regression on it to find a weight set **W**.  Also assume I transform my data by third order polynomial operator **P((x1,x2)) =(1,x1,x2, x1^2, x1*x2, x2^2,x1^3, x1^2 * x2, x1*x2^2, x2^3)**, and run a linear regression on the transformed data and find a weight set **w**.

My goal is to reproduce plots like these. [image]

I know how to plot the line on the left, but I am unsure how to display the 3rd order polynomial.

My idea is to do:

```
plot_poly(X,labels, weights, initial, final, num):
    plt.scatter(X[:, 0][labels=='Blue'], X[:, 1][labels=='Blue'], color='blue', marker = '.')
    plt.scatter(X[:, 0][labels=='Red'], X[:, 1][labels=='Red']], color='red', marker = '.')
    w = weights
    x = np.linspace(initial, final, num)
    y = w[0]*1 + w[1]*(x) + w[2]*(x) + w[3]*(x**2) + w[4]*(x**2) + \
        w[5]*(x**2) + w[6]*(x**3) + w[7]*(x**3) + w[8]*(x**3) + \
        w[9]*(x**3)
    plt.plot(x,y)
```

But when I try this out it seems to fail, specifically the vertical axis becomes so huge that it shrinks the data and the polynomial doesn't come close to the data (Picture below).  Is there a better way to go about plotting this?

[image]

Comment: What part fails?  Could you post the entire function?  It looks like you changed a few things like weights -> w

Comment: @CoryNezin I have edited the code to include the full function and added a graph of the result.

Comment: It seems the issue is with the weights rather than the plot.  Why do you have multiple weights corresponding to each power of x?

Comment: @CoryNezin I'm transforming a linspace set of points to a 3rd order polynomial so I needed a variable x that I could transform.  Since the operator maps x1, x2 --> 1, x1, x2, x1^2, x1*x2, x2^2, etc... I needed a variable x.   But since I needed one variable x, that means x1 = x2 = x so I replaced all of the x1's and x2's with x's.  I can see this is not right now but this is what my thinking was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest approach would be to calculate the values of linear regression function which is function of 2 parameters `X[:, 0]` and `X[:, 1]` and use `plt.contour(..., levels=[0.5])` to plot 2D function. Parameter `levels` tells me what is the decision boundary, which I set in the middle between the labels 0 and 1. Then it plots just one line - the decision boundary.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

def plot_poly(X,labels, weights, initial, final, num):
    plt.scatter(X[:, 0][labels==0], X[:, 1][labels==0], color='blue', marker = '.')
    plt.scatter(X[:, 0][labels==1], X[:, 1][labels==1], color='red', marker = '.')
    w = weights
    xx1 = np.linspace(initial[0], final[0], num)
    xx2 = np.linspace(initial[1], final[1], num)
    z = np.zeros((num, num))
    for i_x1, x1 in enumerate(xx1):
        for i_x2, x2 in enumerate(xx2):
            z[i_x2, i_x1] = \
                w[0]*1 + \
                w[1]*(x1) + w[2]*(x2) + \
                w[3]*(x1**2) + w[4]*(x1*x2) + w[5]*(x2**2) + \
                w[6]*(x1**3) + w[7]*(x1**2*x2) + w[8]*(x1*x2**2) +  w[9]*(x2**3)
    xx1, xx2 = np.meshgrid(xx1, xx2)
    plt.contour(xx1, xx2, z, levels=[0.5])



# import some data to play with
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X_raw = iris.data[:, :2]  # we only take the first two features.
Y = iris.target

# Use only 2 classes
X_raw = X_raw[(Y <= 1), :]
Y = Y[(Y <= 1)]

# Create poly features
poly = PolynomialFeatures(3)
X = poly.fit_transform(X_raw)

# Fit linear regression
linref = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False)
linref.fit(X, Y)

# Plot
x_min, x_max = X_raw[:, 0].min() - .5, X_raw[:, 0].max() + .5
y_min, y_max = X_raw[:, 1].min() - .5, X_raw[:, 1].max() + .5
plot_poly(X_raw, Y, weights=linref.coef_, initial=[x_min, y_min], final=[x_max, y_max], num=60)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Couple of points

- looks like you want to do classification, I would use logistic regression instead of linear regression
- you want to plot 2D function - you can use `plt.pcolormesh`, `plt.contourf`, `plt.contour` or similar

Here is [sklearn example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_iris_logistic.html) that I changed to use polynomial features

```
# Code source: Gaël Varoquaux
# Modified for documentation by Jaques Grobler
# License: BSD 3 clause

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

# import some data to play with
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X_raw = iris.data[:, :2]  # we only take the first two features.
Y = iris.target

poly = PolynomialFeatures(3)
X = poly.fit_transform(X_raw)

logreg = LogisticRegression(C=1e5, solver='lbfgs', multi_class='multinomial')

# we create an instance of Neighbours Classifier and fit the data.
logreg.fit(X, Y)

# Plot the decision boundary. For that, we will assign a color to each
# point in the mesh [x_min, x_max]x[y_min, y_max].
x_min, x_max = X_raw[:, 0].min() - .5, X_raw[:, 0].max() + .5
y_min, y_max = X_raw[:, 1].min() - .5, X_raw[:, 1].max() + .5
h = .02  # step size in the mesh
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h), np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
X_plot_raw = np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()]
X_plot = poly.transform(X_plot_raw)
Z = logreg.predict(X_plot)

# Put the result into a color plot
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
plt.figure(1, figsize=(4, 3))
plt.pcolormesh(xx, yy, Z, cmap=plt.cm.Paired)

# Plot also the training points
plt.scatter(X_raw[:, 0], X_raw[:, 1], c=Y, edgecolors='k', cmap=plt.cm.Paired)
plt.xlabel('Sepal length')
plt.ylabel('Sepal width')

plt.xlim(xx.min(), xx.max())
plt.ylim(yy.min(), yy.max())
plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I am asking specifically about how to plot a 3rd order polynomial manually using the weights given from applying linear regression to the data set.  Do you know of a way to do this?